# How to identify QListWidget in Python/Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

With a row of QListWidgets I wonder if there is a simple way to label each so the user would be able to say which List is which.
Here is a dialog's screenshot a code posted below results.
I avoid using any widgets outside of QListWidgets(). Ideal solution would be solved utilizing QListWidgets itself. It would be great if there is a way to place a text line-label similar to those available for QGroupBox with .setTitle('myString'). At very least an ability to place a label as a first list item would be sufficient too...

---

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.groupbox.setTitle('My Groupbox')
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.listGroupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.listLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.listGroupbox.setLayout(self.listLayout)
        self.listA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.listB=QtGui.QListWidget()

        self.listLayout.addWidget(self.listA)
        self.listLayout.addWidget(self.listB)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listGroupbox) 

        self.okButton = QtGui.QPushButton('OK')
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.OK) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.okButton)                      
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.groupbox)
        self.mainWidget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def OK(self):
        print 'Ok'    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp()
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no (Qt-native) way to label a `QListView` (on which `QListWidget` is based). If your really don't want additional widgets, I would instead use a single-column `QTableWidget`, and put the list title in the column header. `QTableWidget` and `QListWidget` work pretty similarly, so this probably won't break too much of your existing code.

An example based on yours:

```
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):

        # snipped

        self.listA = self.prepareTableWidget('List A')
        self.listB = self.prepareTableWidget('List B')

        # snipped

    def prepareTableWidget(self, name):
        table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        table.setColumnCount(1)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([name])
        table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        return table

    # snipped
```

[image: QTableWidget example]

Comment: As long as suggested QtGui.QTableWidget() supports 'most popular' QListWidget() features I am in... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to achieve it without abandoning QListWidget()... utilizing layout's .insertLayout() method to attach QLabel without losing GUI space usually taken by QGroupBox()...

[image]

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.groupbox.setTitle('My Groupbox')
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.listGroupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.listLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.listGroupbox.setLayout(self.listLayout)
        self.listA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.listB=QtGui.QListWidget()

        self.subLayoutA=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()        
        self.listLayout.insertLayout(0,self.subLayoutA)
        self.subLayoutA.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label A') )
        self.subLayoutA.addWidget(self.listA)

        self.subLayoutB=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.listLayout.insertLayout(1,self.subLayoutB)
        self.subLayoutB.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Label B') )
        self.subLayoutB.addWidget(self.listB)


        self.layout.addWidget(self.listGroupbox) 

        self.okButton = QtGui.QPushButton('OK')
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.OK) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.okButton)                      
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.groupbox)
        self.mainWidget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def OK(self):
        print 'Ok'    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp()
```